# The plot of a decomposed time series shows extra time period

Tags: r, time-series

My multivariate time series (`mts`) has the time index from 2005 to 2007 as shown below

```
hom_rate_combo <- ts(
  matrix(
    c(
      0.473354345, 0.431411555, 0.46137069, 0.50331348, 0.581207233, 0.443395209,
      0.539264443, 0.509305308, 0.605174542, 0.515297135, 0.509305308, 0.467362518,
      0.488117572, 0.429308226, 0.51164131, 0.499879441, 0.493998506, 0.529284114,
      0.493998506, 0.593974394, 0.482236637, 0.541045983, 0.429308226, 0.411665422,
      0.465108267, 0.470850344, 0.430655803, 0.482334499, 0.482334499, 0.551239427,
      0.637370588, 0.539755273, 0.499560731, 0.499560731, 0.447882035, 0.419171648,
      0.453984979, 0.313866159, 0.448380226, 0.414751709, 0.453984979, 0.521242013,
      0.577289542, 0.470799238, 0.392332698, 0.510032508, 0.521242013, 0.51563726,
      0.555953102, 0.550448616, 0.407331976, 0.517421699, 0.64402488, 0.495403754,
      0.594484505, 0.588980019, 0.528430671, 0.64402488, 0.511917213, 0.64402488,
      0.680538769, 0.413767572, 0.604318427, 0.615207047, 0.631539978, 0.598874117,
      0.783980662, 0.566208256, 0.587985496, 0.517209464, 0.598874117, 0.609762737
    ),
    nrow = 36L,
    ncol = 2L,
    dimnames = list(NULL, c("ctrl", "trmt"))
  ),
  frequency = 12,
  start = 2005
)

> time(hom_rate_combo)
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2005 2005.000 2005.083 2005.167 2005.250 2005.333 2005.417 2005.500 2005.583 2005.667 2005.750 2005.833 2005.917
2006 2006.000 2006.083 2006.167 2006.250 2006.333 2006.417 2006.500 2006.583 2006.667 2006.750 2006.833 2006.917
2007 2007.000 2007.083 2007.167 2007.250 2007.333 2007.417 2007.500 2007.583 2007.667 2007.750 2007.833 2007.917
```

However, when I plotted the decomposed `mts`, it showed extra time period (2008-2011).

```
plot(decompose(hom_rate_combo), xlim=c(2005, 2007))
```

[image]

What happened and how I could limit the x-axis to 2005-2007 only?

Comment: "when I plotted the decomposed mts" how? harder to diagnose code issues w/o code. Can you share the output of `dput(hom_rate_combo)` as well?

Comment: Good question. Thanks @JonSpring!

Comment: Investigating why and what to do about it, but I see that `decompose(hom_rate_combo)$seasonal` has 72 elements, while your data had 36. I see that `?decompose` notes that "This only works well if x covers an integer number of complete periods"

Comment: Quick hack without understanding or fixing it: `a <- decompose(hom_rate_combo); a$seasonal = a$seasonal[1:36]; 
plot(a, xlim=c(2005, 2007))`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you @JonSpring.